# Get ASP.NET Core 8 MVC controller to return JSON properties unchanged without lowercasing property names

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, json.net

I have an ASP.NET Core 8 controller.

When I return an object serialized using `Newtonsoft.Json` in the `Ok` return below, it changes the properties to lower case in the JSON.

I want them to stay as declared in C# without having to put `JsonPropertyName` attribute on all the properties.

Instead of this:

```
{ 
   "id":"0",
   "name": "Foo"
}
```

I want to get this representation instead:

```
{ "Id: "0", "Name": "Foo" }
```

This is the C# class for this:

```
class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

/// </summary>
[ApiController]
public class ManagerApiController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("/api/v1/search-approval-workflows")]
    [ValidateModelState]
    [SwaggerOperation("SearchApprovalWorkflowsGet")]
    public virtual IActionResult SearchApprovalWorkflowsGet([FromQuery] string s)
    {
         // ...
         return OK(foo);
    }
}
```

I tried

```
DefaultContractResolver resolver = 
   new DefaultContractResolver
       {
           NamingStrategy = new DefaultNamingStrategy()
       };

resolver.NamingStrategy.OverrideSpecifiedNames = false;

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings
                                               {
                                                   ContractResolver = resolver,
                                                   Formatting = Formatting.Indented
                                               });
return json;
```

But that didn't work.

I also tried returning `new JsonResult(foo)`, but again without luck.

Comment: builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => 
options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);

Comment: there is a solution for net8 here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59559560/change-json-serialization-from-camelcase-to-pascalcase-duplicate-no-solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off or handle camelCasing in JSON response ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728200/how-to-turn-off-or-handle-camelcasing-in-json-response-asp-net-core)

Comment: OP stated they are using newtonsoft.json serializer, your suggestions seem to relate to system.text.json serializer.

Comment: That last code snippet in the question should work. Are you absolutely sure the `json` value had camelCase property names in that scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks PowerMouse.

This was it.  Example shows for json.net and newtonsoft, maybe only one needed depending on what is used.

```
services
      .AddMvc().AddJsonOptions( jsonOpt =>
      {
          jsonOpt.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
      })
      .AddNewtonsoftJson(opts =>
      {
          opts.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = null;
       
      })
```